# Hadoop ssh configuration pseudo-distributed mode

Tags: ssh, hadoop

I'm trying to install hadoop locally.  Basically, I followed the steps in "Hadoop - the definitive guide".

Everything worked fine, including the ssh configuration. Actually this is not the first time when I install hadoop.

However when I try to run start-all.sh script, I get this error:

```
localhost: @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
localhost: @    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
localhost: @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
localhost: IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
localhost: Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
localhost: It is also possible that the RSA host key has just been changed.
localhost: The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
localhost: 42:e7:95:2a:32:ac:3b:7e:fa:40:09:0d:b5:01:ed:21.
localhost: Please contact your system administrator.
localhost: Add correct host key in /home/rbelet/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this  msg.
localhost: Offending key in /home/rbelet/.ssh/known_hosts:1
localhost: RSA host key for localhost has changed and you have requested strict checking.
localhost: Host key verification failed.
```

As far as I understand I should add the public key of the localhost server to the file known_host. Am I right ?

Any ideas what to do?

Comment: Remove all your ssh keys on both sides (client and server) and try again.

Comment: The client and the server are both running on the same machines, so shoul I remove the public my public key for ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

Comment: So your server's public key is stored at two places. One is for the client, usually in .ssh/known_hosts/ directory, and the other one you just mentioned. Remove these files.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a hadoop issue but a pure SSH related stuff. It looks like you had added localhost node to your known hosts file some time back. Now when you connect to it, it has a different public key so ssh realises that someone is attempting to perform a man in the middle attack. You can reset the keys freshly to get rid of this.